# SQL Server Subquery causing error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am used to Firebird queries and now I need to make one in SQL Server, but I am getting an error with the subquery.

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'

Query:

```
SELECT 
    CVE_ART, IIF (CANTIDAD < 0, 0, CANTIDAD) AS CANTIDAD    
FROM
    (SELECT     
         CVE_ART,    
         SUM((CANT * SIGNO * -1) / 6) AS CANTIDAD    
     FROM   
         MINVE05    
     WHERE     
         DATEDIFF(MONTH, FECHA_DOCU, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) >  0    
         AND DATEDIFF(MONTH, FECHA_DOCU, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) <= 6    
         AND CVE_CPTO IN (2, 4, 51)    
         AND ALMACEN = 1    
     GROUP BY 
         CVE_ART)
```

Comment: what is the error ? please post the error message

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: You tagged 3 different version of SQL Server. Be sure to only tag the relevant one. This error would be the same on all versions, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to give a alias name to the derived table

```
SELECT CVE_ART, IIF (CANTIDAD<0,0,CANTIDAD) AS CANTIDAD   
FROM
(
    . . . 
) AS something
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not write the query like this?

```
SELECT CVE_ART,    
       (CASE WHEN SUM((CANT*SIGNO*-1)/6) < 0 THEN 0
             ELSE SUM((CANT*SIGNO*-1)/6)
        END) AS CANTIDAD    
FROM   MINVE05    
WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH, FECHA_DOCU, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) > 0  AND  
      DATEDIFF(MONTH, FECHA_DOCU, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) <= 6    
      CVE_CPTO IN (2, 4, 51) AND  
      ALMACEN = 1    
GROUP BY CVE_ART ;
```

The subquery actually does not do much for the query, except take up space.  The use of `DATEDIFF()` is curious.  It counts *boundaries* between two dates.  So, the first is saying that the calendar months of the two dates are different.  So, 2018-01-31 and 2018-02-01 meet the condition, but 2018-01-01 and 2018-01-31 do not.